# What does "las" refer to in "arreglárselas"

Tags: etimología

"arreglárselas" means to manage, to cope. But what does "las" refers to as the object of the verb?

For example,
"Se las arregló para llegar tarde"

Comment: Can you give us the whole sentence?

Comment: En español se dice con muchíssima frecuencia: arreglar las cosas. Y cuando hay un lío, pues, se puede perfectamente decir: Bueno, a ver si podemos arreglárselas [entre estas dos personas]. Creo que de allí viene este las.

Answer (score 1):

*La*, and, especially, *las*, are used as dummy pronouns in many expressions: they don't necessarily refer to anything specific. It's called "el femenino de indeterminación".

The feminine and the feminine plural object pronouns are used because they are marked--they stand out--due to the fact that the masculine is the "neutral" gender, gramatically speaking (as any woman in a group of men could tell you); not to mention that the actual neuter accusative pronoun is the same as the masculine (that is, *lo*, as in "Lo haré", could refer to any masculine noun, verb, phrase, *algo*, *eso*, *aquello*, etc.).

> «Sin asociarse con ninguna clase semántica determinada, es en todo caso frecuente que aparezca el plural en las locuciones: en cueros, en ciernes, en tiempos, a cuestas, de perillas, en puertas de, a buenas horas, hacer aguas menores, hacer de tripas (*tripa) corazón; la vacuidad del plural se pone de relieve en casos como de perillas y de perilla, perfectamente conmutables. **También es muy propio de modismos el uso de un femenino con escaso o nulo correlato semántico** (por la tremenda, a la primera, en una de estas, no dar una, tener la negra, estar a la que salta), sobre todo en plural y muchas veces en binomios: en volandas, por las malas, a las claras, a sabiendas, a tientas, de oídas, a solas, tomar las de Villadiego, a tontas y a locas, estar a las duras y a las maduras. **No es seguramente necesario dar más pruebas de que ni estos plurales ni estos femeninos son significativos en cuanto tales: añadamos sin más que el pasarlo bien de unos países es sinónimo del pasarla bien de otros.** Debe constar sin embargo que las diferencias de flexión se usan también para formar modismos igualmente diferenciados: compárese de buena gana con ¡Buenas ganas!, con vistas a y en vista de; ¡Qué bien se lo monta! con ¡La que ha montado...! **Hay asimismo un uso idiomático muy productivo del clítico la** (diñarla, fastidiarla, cargársela), **también en plural en muchos casos** (verlas venir, pasarlas moradas, se las trae, ni las huele).

[Piera, Carlos / Varela, Soledad: „Relaciones entre morfología y sintaxis“. En: Bosque, Ignacio / Demonte, Violeta (eds.): Gramática descriptiva de la lengua española. Madrid: Real Academia Española / Espasa Calpe. 1999, § 67.3.1.1, pp. 4404-4405]

To use the expression in the title:

Ahora los arreglo = I will take care of/fix them (some masculine noun, let's say "los daños")

Me las arreglo = I am managing/figuring it out (*las* refers to a vague notion of "something", and, combined with the reflexive pronoun, it slightly alters the meaning of the verb)(*it* in the English expression functions in much the same way as *las*).

Comment: Why don't you make up an example in Spanish? So the OP can see it.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this? For example, "te las veras conmigo" probably means "te verás las caras conmigo"

Comment: People say that *las* in *arreglárselas* means "las puntillas", but much of these are a type of folk etymology where people fill in the blanks with nouns that make sense. I have found papers about the phenomenon online; I'll try to find some again.

Comment: arreglar las cosas entre dos personas....

Comment: There are a few PDFs out there, but this webpage says largely what they point out, in far less detail: http://usoadecuadodelalenguaescrita.blogspot.com/2009/01/femenino-indeterminacion.html?m=1

Comment: https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/1496-locuciones-verbales-arreglarselas-darselas-versela-liarla Although, I find it hard to believe that *pasarla bien* refers to "la situación/coyuntura", especially in colloquial language, and especially since in Spain and other places the same expression with the neuter/masculine pronoun is used (*pasarlo bien*).

Comment: Hi @nopaltepec, if you update the answer to mention the "Femenino de indeterminación" and find a more "official" link, say Panhispánico de dudas, RAE or similar, I'll approve

Comment: Great answer! I wonder why it doesn’t have any more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

---

Que tal? *Arreglárselas*

Los Clíticos

Un clítico es un elemento gramatical que se escribe como una palabra o partícula independiente, pero que en realidad se pronuncia como parte de la palabra anterior o siguiente

En español son clíticos los pronombres la, lo, le, los, las, les (que señalan objeto directo o indirecto pronominal de tercera persona), entre otros.

Cómete (la manzana)
Cómete(la)

Algunos verbos se construyen con una combinación de se + pronombre como arreglárselas, apañárselas, antojársele (algo a alguien), ocurrírsele (algo a alguien).

Construcción de Arreglárselas;

- Yo me las arreglo - (A mi) se me ocurre (una idea).
- Tu te las arreglas - (A ti) se te ocurre (una idea).
- El se las arregla - (A él) se le ocurre (una idea).
- Nosotros nos la arreglamos - (A nosotros) se nos ocurre (una idea).
- Vosotros os las arregláis - (A vosotros) se os ocurre (una idea).
- Ellos se las arreglan - (A ellos) se les ocurre (una idea).

Otros significados para arreglar;

Modificar algo para que se ajuste a una regla.
Reparar una falla o defecto.
Adaptar una pieza musical siguiendo un criterio.
Establecer un acuerdo.
Poner, disponer, ordenar, colocar en toda regla.
Zanjar, componer, transigir asuntos contenciosos, avenir partes contrarias.
Cambiar el estado de un elemento para que esté nuevamente en condiciones de trabajar.
Ordenar, componer, ajustar una cosa.
Decorar, embellecer. lavar y poner ropa limpia y elegante a alguien.
Adornar, acicalar. adaptar, ajustar. poner en regla.

Espero haya servido. Saludos.

Diego M.